# VB.NET Application freezes when minimizing

Tags: vb.net, forms, freeze, minimize

I have a windows forms application consisting of a single form which parses a large body of text upon clicking a few buttons.

There is a huge chunk of code which parses through every node of an XML file, typically around 5000 nodes containing 20-ish child nodes, and those have even more children, and so on and so forth, just to create an image of the file's size.

While iterating through the code, as in when the data is being parsed, if I press the minimize button, it won't minimize but goes into the "not responding" state. My guess is that the minimize function can't be processed while the data is being parsed.

Is there a way to set an interrupt to the minimize/maximize/close buttons, or set priority to them, or any other solution to enable smooth minimisation of the form?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Move your parsing code to a background thread instead of using the main GUI thread.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to add almost the same answer as Stephan, but waited 10 hours for him to remove the `DoEvents` thing.

Data gathering or parsing should be handled in another Thread. The simpliest way is to use a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx), and implementing at least two event handlers :

```
BGWorker_DoWork(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DoWorkEventArgs)
' Move your parsing code here
' use local variables whenever possible
' do the appropriate changes

' and
BGWorker_RunWorkerCompleted( _
    ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs)
' tells your Main thread that it can use the resuls
```

> **Note :**
>   You must be careful not to manipulate any **user-interface** objects
>   in your **`DoWork`** event handler. Instead, communicate to the user
>   interface through the **`ProgressChanged`** and **`RunWorkerCompleted`**
>   events.

---

*And I would add :*
Everything your BGW needs in its DoWork *should remain untouched* (*) by any other code. The DoWork() can access anything in your main thread (ex : manipulating a class instance of FileContent, calling a Function, reading a static variable...) *You shouldn't take that lightly !* This could produce unexpected behaviours due to **interference** like multiple Workers, states changes or User inputs.

User inputs interfering with the parsing process *should* be handled : use the `.RunWorkerCompleted(..)` to capture when your main thread can safely (let user) access and manipulate datas, change states, etc.

(*) Best move is to make everything required by your BGW as a **copy** of the actual values at the beginning of the work. If you have a very long task to do, and states changes could occur in the meantime (ex : filesystem hierachy + file deletion - date changing while running a code that orders results by time...) you should :

- either think again, whether all the required tools are available in your code to properly complete the task (best case)
- either carefully handle the `.Error` Property of the `RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs` parameter (then fix the error, and try again..)
- either validate your data integrity prior to use them (worst scenario)

---

EDIT : BGW is not the only way. Have a look at [Threads and Threading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6kac2kdh.aspx) while following [Managed Threading Best Practices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1c9txz50.aspx) advices.

Comment: Good answer, although its a saying to not touch any UI objects using the DoWork, but is fine using proper delegates. Its a trade off I would say.

Comment: Thanks, I thought multithreading would be one possible option but I wanted to avoid it exactly because of the possible instability. However, since the XML is parsed on fixed parameters and once loaded into the application has no contact with the user until the parsing finishes, it should be more than plausible to do. Thanks again!

Comment: @Flopn - In that case, disallows user inputs **in exchange** of a visual control **showing** the progression of the XML loading. You may achieve this with a BackgroundWorker (better) or by creating a `modal DialogBox` **with a ProgressBar** that **self close** itself when the loading is complete. That's the simpliest way avoiding you to use a parallel thread, but that's not usually considered "pro", and I know why : I'm using that _modal way_ every day and it's not funny to wait several seconds each time. However, without a modal dialog, I would have to disable 40 controls to disallow user IO.

Answer (score -1):

Since you are parsing your XML in your main thread, the GUI can't update until the parsing is finish. The best option is to use the [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). It will start an other thread that permit you to execute the parsing of your file while leaving the GUI responsive to the user input.

Comment: You wouldnt call DoEvents many times period. If a message causes an event to be triggered, then other areas of your application code may execute. This can cause your application to exhibit unexpected behaviors that are difficult to debug... It also suspends the current thread until all messages have been processed. As you have stated a BackgroundWorker would suffice OR another thread.